# Spring stomp web sockets client for android

Tags: android, websocket, push-notification, spring-boot, stomp

Can somebody please let me know how to connect to spring stomp web socket from android client.

WebSocketConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/pushticket");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/rest");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ticket").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

PushMessageNotifier.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;    

@Service
@EnableAsync
public class PushMessageNotifier {

    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public PushMessageNotifier(SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate) {
        this.simpMessagingTemplate = simpMessagingTemplate;
    }

    @Async
    public Boolean pushToUI(TicketView ticketView) {
        Boolean result = false;
        if (null != ticketView) {
            this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/pushticket/ticket", ticketView);
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Please tell me how can I connect to this socket from android app? Even I don't have idea which android client I need to use to connect to this socket and topic.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Pratap, im facing similiar problem.. can you please tell me how did you resolved this problem? thanks!

Comment: @programmerX We didn't use this approach, instead we used RabbitMQ to achieve push notifications for android devices

Comment: Thanks for input! @Pratap. I got the solution though, FYI, refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56970860/5576205

Comment: @programmerX sure!! I'll take a look

Answer (score 4):

Its been ages since the question is asked but it shows up on google and have not received any accepted answer hence...

- this can be achieved easily using following library
  https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid
- **Important note:**  which documentation fails to communicate effectively:
  In case of `SockJS` lets assume we have to use URL like `http://server-host:8080/stompEndpoint` but in android it must be `ws://server-host:8080/stompEndpoint/websocket`. Where differences are **1) `http` vs `ws` 2) Appended `/websocket` in android variant of URL**

Comment: Life saver! Thank you a lot. Still solves problem in 2023.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through same issue . I found spring provides default web-socket connector library I used those to test my  code for server side .

```
@LocalServerPort
private int port;

private SockJsClient sockJsClient;

private WebSocketStompClient stompClient;

private final WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();

@Before
public void setup() {
    List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>();
    transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient()));
    this.sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);

    this.stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
    this.stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
}

@Test
public void getGreeting() throws Exception {

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final AtomicReference<Throwable> failure = new AtomicReference<>();

    StompSessionHandler handler = new TestSessionHandler(failure) {

        @Override
        public void afterConnected(final StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
            session.subscribe("/user/testuser1/reply", new StompFrameHandler() {
                @Override
                public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
                    return Greeting.class;
                }

                @Override
                public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                    MessageSendDTO greeting = (MessageSendDTO) payload;
                    try {
                        System.out.println("#################### "+greeting.getWriter());
                        assertEquals("testuser1", greeting.getWriter());
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        failure.set(t);
                    } finally {
                        session.disconnect();
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                }
            });
            try {

                MessageSendDTO dto= new MessageSendDTO();
                dto.setWriter("testuser1");
                dto.setReceiver("testuser2");
                dto.setMessageBody("TESTING ");

                GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson = builder.create();

               //session.send("/app/newMessage", new HelloMessage("Spring"));
                session.send("/app/newMessage", dto);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                failure.set(t);
                latch.countDown();
            }
        }
    };

    this.stompClient.connect("ws://localhost:8080/newMessage", this.headers, handler, this.port);

    if (latch.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        if (failure.get() != null) {
            throw new AssertionError("", failure.get());
        }
    }
    else {
        fail("Greeting not received");
    }
```

This code works fine . You can use this  for your android with little modification and all  the dependency for this can be downloaded from [here](https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=spring-websocket&g=org.springframework&v=4.2.1.RELEASE&downloadable=1).